# Bug working with tagged services in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have the following services (only):

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.google_service_gmail.watcher_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Provider\Google\Service\Gmail\Watch\WatcherManager

    app.google_service_gmail.mail_watcher:
        class: AppBundle\Provider\Google\Service\Gmail\Watch\MailWatcher
        tags:
            - { name: app.watcher }
```

I have the `WatcherManager` class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Provider\Google\Service\Gmail\Watch;

class WatcherManager
{

    /**
     * @var WatcherInterface[]
     */
    private $watchers = [];

    /**
     * Add a Watcher
     *
     * @param WatcherInterface $watcher
     *
     * @return WatcherManager
     */
    public function addWatcher(WatcherInterface $watcher)
    {
        $this->watchers[] = $watcher;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The following compiler pass class:

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\CompilerPass;

use ...

class WatcherCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('app.google_service_gmail.watcher_manager')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition(
            'app.google_service_gmail.watcher_manager'
        );

        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(
            'app.watcher'
        );

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
            $definition->addMethodCall('addWatcher', [new Reference($id)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering compiler pass:

```
namespace AppBundle;

use ...

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new WatcherCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Getting the following exception to the execute any console command:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]
>    Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.

Running application across browser:

> RuntimeException in XmlDumper.php line 355:
>   Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.

```
in XmlDumper.php line 355
at XmlDumper::phpToXml(object(Reference)) in XmlDumper.php line 304
at XmlDumper->convertParameters(array(object(Reference)), 'argument', object(DOMElement)) in XmlDumper.php line 98
at XmlDumper->addMethodCalls(array(array('addWatcher', array(object(Reference)))), object(DOMElement)) in XmlDumper.php line 181
at XmlDumper->addService(object(Definition), 'app.google_service_gmail.watcher_manager', object(DOMElement)) in XmlDumper.php line 248
at XmlDumper->addServices(object(DOMElement)) in XmlDumper.php line 56
at XmlDumper->dump() in ContainerBuilderDebugDumpPass.php line 34
at ContainerBuilderDebugDumpPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 117
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 614
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2633
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2411
at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2442
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 29
```

I check the symfony documentation:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

and the code is exactly the same.

If I disable this line code:

```
$definition->addMethodCall('addWatcher', [new Reference($id)]);
```

all work fine. **Any idea??**

Comment: Could you provide your `composer.json` so I can test it?

Comment: composer.json: https://gist.github.com/yceruto/0851c990486d0b59d64d

Comment: Check your "use" statements at the CompilerPass, maybe you have a type error in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference.

Comment: Resolved! thanks @VadimKharitonov "type error"